# AWS Lambda function is timing out when invoking another Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function (trigger) which invokes another Lambda function (worker).  Both are written in Python 3.8.

The invocation is via boto3:

```
invokeResponse = lambdaClient.invoke(
            # FunctionName="worker_function",
            FunctionName="somearn",
            InvocationType="Event",
            LogType="Tail",
            Payload=payload,
        )
```

The trigger script gets to the invocation line and then hangs until timeout (tested up to 8 minutes for the trigger).  The worker function can be manually tested successfully, and it completes in <20 seconds.

Both scripts are in the same VPC, so I assume its not a network connectivity issue?

To try to exclude permissions issues, I've tried granting trigger AWSLambda_FullAccess, still no change.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm so annoyed.

I've been banging my head against this brick wall for hours.

Turns out I had not added a VPC endpoint for Lambda.

I think the act of writing it all out may have given me some clarity.

Resolved.

Comment: Yeah I was about to post that "both lambda functions in the same vpc" is irrelevant since Lambda functions never have direct network connectivity with each other. The first function needs network access to the AWS Lambda API, which was missing until you added the VPC endpoint.